# To self or not to self?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't quite understand if I need the `self` argument in the call to the `super` class method when inheriting, as I'm having trouble with repeated parameter definition errors when using it.

The code is basically:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    def method(self, arg=None):
        arg=f(arg)
        super(MyClass, self).method(self, arg=None)
```

With `self` in the `super` call, I get that:

> TypeError: method() got multiple values for keyword argument 'arg'`

Without, it seems to work, but I don't know whether I will miss out on any side-effects that I need. Is it that `self` is in the `super` statement?

Comment: Which python version is this, as in python 3, its just `super().method(arg=None)`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to supply `self` in the call to `method`; it should work completely fine without. (Is that your question?)

Comment: Yes. So is it that `self` is in `super(MyClass, self)` thereby making the call to the self instance in the superclass?

Comment: @DavidBoshton `super(MyClass, self).method(arg=None)` would be fine.

Comment: Hence the error. `self` is passed to `arg`, `arg` is then defined again as `None` and python hence raises an error.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)!

Here's how you should use `super`:

```
super(MyClass, self).method(arg=None)
```

You have to pass `self` to the `super` call, not the method call.

Also, If you are using Python 3, it's even simpler:

```
super().method(arg=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't supply the self explicitly in the arguments of `method`, it is not needed.

In python 2 it is still needed where you have it in the arguments of `super`.  Note in python3 this would just be `super()`.

Comment: I wanted to put my comment as an answer, but I wasn't sure if it was sufficient. I suppose this really is all there is to it.